# Alphametics puzzle, given numbers that are prime and square.

Tags: puzzle

I have been trying puzzle solving recently and came across this problem (sorry if this is not entirely appropriate on a maths stack exchange, I have also posted this on the puzzle one).

[image]

Any hints on how to do this?

So far, I have found that N, R and F must be odd (as they are the last digit in a 5 digit prime number), and that N must be specifically either 1,5 or 9, because all square numbers end in either 1,4,9,5 or 6, and N can’t be 4 or 6, because it must be odd. Finally, I think E must be even because N-E=R, and since N and R are odd, E must be even.

However, these observations don’t seem to be getting me anywhere.

Comment: $U$ must be $0$ if $N < E$ or $9$ if $N > E$, because it is the result of $E - E$ with a possible borrowing. Also, $N$ can't be $5$, because $SEVEN$ would be divisible by $5$.

Comment: Notice $N$ can't be $5$ because $SEVEN$ is prime.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Do you have the inequality reversed?  If $N>E$ then $R=N-E$ and $U=E-E=0.$

Comment: @saulspatz Yes I do.

Comment: Since $SEVEN-THREE=FOUR$ we must have $S=T+1$ or the difference would have $5$ digits.  Then $TEN$ is a three-digit square, with $3$ different digits, ending in an odd number, whose first digit is not $9$. I can't think of anything better than to test each case.  For example, the smallest possibility is $TEN=169,$ which leads to $SEVEN = 26V69,$ which is not possible, by examination of a table of primes.

Comment: There are only four possibilities for TEN: 169, 361, 729, 841.

Comment: @rogerl $361$ is not a possibility because $E-N=5$ gives $R=5$ which is impossible since $FOUR$ is prime.

Comment: Since 169 is also impossible, we must have TEN=729 or 841, then. But 729 is impossible since F and R must both be odd, so one of them is 5. Thus TEN=841, so that S=9$. Note that V must now be even; the only prime of the form 94V41 with V even is 94841.

Comment: You're forgetting $529$, are you not?

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes, and in fact 529 is correct. I'll refrain from posting the complete solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your reasoning, we know that $N$ is $1$ or $9$. If it is $1$, then $U$ is $9$, and if it is $9$, $U$ is $0$, because $U$ is a result of the $E-E$ with possible borrowing from $SEVEN - THREE$. This means no other letter can be $9$.

We know that $S = T+1$ and $H > E$, because there had to be a borrowing to get a four-digit number. Since none of these letters can be $9$, we know that $E$ and $T$ also can't be $8$. The condition that $TEN$ is a square, leaves $169,361,529,729$. However, in the last case, $R = N-E$ would be $7$, not distinct from $T$, and in the second case, $R = 10 + N - E = 5$, making $FOUR$ divisible by $5$. So $N = 9$, $U = 0$, and $TEN = 169,529$. This means $SEVEN$ is either $26V69$ or $62V29$. However, in the first case, that would mean $16 - H = F$, but that's not possible as they must be distinct and neither can be $9$ (there can't be a borrow because $R = 3$ and $1$ and $2$ are already taken as values for $V$). So $SEVEN = 62V29$.

So $SEVEN - THREE = FOUR$ is now $62V29 - 5H722 = FO07$. We know $F + H = 11$ or $F + H = 12$, depending on whether there's a borrow. Since $RUOF$ is prime and the only odd digits left are $1$ and $3$, $F$ must be one of them, but it can't be $1$ and satisfy either equation. So $F$ is $3$. $H$ must then be $8$, because $9$ is taken. Thus, there must have been a borrow in $V - 7 = O$, which is satisfied by $V = 1$, $O = 4$.

Thus, $SEVEN - THREE = FOUR$ is
$$
62129 - 58722  = 3407
$$
and checking [the prime table](https://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/100000.txt) shows $62129$, $3407$, and $7043$ are indeed prime. Meanwhile, $TEN = 529 = 23^2$ is a perfect square, as desired.

As a fun aside, $FOURTEEN$ is prime but $SEVENTEEN$ is not.

EDIT: removed reliance on prime table.

Comment: So in the puzzle, the information that $RUOF$ is prime is superfluous, correct?

Comment: @saulspatz it eliminated $F = 8$.

Comment: So it did.  Thanks.

Comment: @saulspatz it turns out the prime table isn't necessary. see edited answer.

Comment: Elegant solution. +1

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the help. After looking at some of the initial hints, I was able to get the correct answer. As a note, I was going to upload the actual method as I saw the answers were quite long, and not in the style of where I got the question from, but after looking at the official answer given, your answer was spot on and it doesn’t seem there is a much shorter way to do it. Once again, thanks!

Comment: Reassuringly, ONE is not prime.